# Knockout Subscribe Syntax

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How would I call a function inside "subscribe" instead of writing it inline?

For example, if I have:

```
function Car(name) {

var self = this;
self.name = name;
self.isRed = ko.observable(isRed);

self.isRed.subscribe(function (value) {console.log(this.name()}, this)

}
```

Everything works as expected and the value of [this.name] is output.

But I'd like to replace the function body something like:

```
self.isRed.subscribe(function (value) {outputLog(value)}, this)
```

If I do this, however, the value of [this.name] is undefined within the outputlog function.

I'm new to both javascript and knockout so I suspect I'm missing something fundamental about javascript.  I'm assuming it has to do with the scope of [this] but I can't figure out how to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hv9Dx/12/):

```
self.isRed.subscribe(
   function (value) {
     outputLog.call(this, value);
   }
, this)
```

Here's a nice article about the this keyword: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: thanks - between your linked article and this one: https://justin.harmonize.fm/development/2009/09/26/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this.html the pattern is becoming clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In your function 'this' now has different context.
As you've declared self in your object if your outputLog function is a property of car, you could do self.name instead.